# File format 'GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sowfalke - I am trying to run the following query to pull data from a file stored in ASW S3.

```
select $1 as blah, $2 as blahh, $3 as blahhh, $4 as blahhhh, $5 as val, 'blahhhhh' as version
from  '@blah.csv.gz' (FILE_FORMAT => shared.GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT)
;
```

But I get this error:

```
SQL compilation error: File format 'GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Even more confused, because this job runs overnight during an ETL and works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a context and/or permissions issue. Check what default database and schema are used in the ETL process, also try running SHOW FILE FORMATS to see if you can actually see that format.

Comment: run show file formats on what - my role?

Comment: Yes, this is a test to see if you have permission on the file format. If you don't you won't see it. Presumably it does actually exist since your ETL is using it, but that process may run under a different user/role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use 1 role at a time. So make sure the role you are using has access to that FILE FORMAT.

You can either grant the FILE FORMAT access to the role you are using:

```
GRANT USAGE on FILE FORMAT GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT to ROLE YOUR_ROLE;
```

OR Grant a role that you know has access to that FILE FORMAT to the role you are using:

```
GRANT ROLE FILE_FORMAT_ACCESS_ROLE TO ROLE YOUR_ROLE;
```

Comment: Why does it not work when I try and use the ETL role?

Comment: If you know the role has access to it then you also need to make sure that you have your DATABASE and SCHEMA context set correctly. File format "shared.GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT" exists in a DB and Schema.. your code above is qualified to the schema but not the DB. If you are in the Snowflake GUI then make sure your session is set to the DB where the schema SHARED exists that contains that file format.  OR fully qualify as "MYDB.SHARED.GZIP_TRANSFER_FORMAT"

Answer (score 1):

"gzip" is often also used to refer to the gzip file format and it is authorised. Each single file is compressed into single file. "gz" suffix deletes the original file. With no arguments, gzib compresses the standard input and writes the compressed file to standard output.